# Pandas dataframe add integer columns into datetime columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a column named `transaction_date` which stores date, `1970-01-01` for example, and `payment_plan_days` stores the amount of days, 30, 70, any integer.

How should I add `payment_plan_days` into `transaction_date` to create a new column as `membership_expire_date` ?

I had tried with code below and it doesn't work since they are not the same dtype.

```
df_transactions.loc[(df_transactions['membership_expire_date'] == '19700101'), 'membership_expire_date'] = 
    df_transactions.loc[(df_transactions['membership_expire_date'] == '19700101'), 'transaction_date'] 
    + df_transactions.loc[(df_transactions['membership_expire_date'] == '19700101'), 'payment_plan_days']
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you need [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_timedelta.html):

```
df['new'] = df['transaction_date'] + pd.to_timedelta(df['payment_plan_days'], unit='d')
```

Sample:

```
dates=pd.to_datetime(['1970-01-01','2005-07-17', '2005-07-17'])
df = pd.DataFrame({'transaction_date':dates, 'payment_plan_days':[30,70,100]})

df['new'] = df['transaction_date'] + pd.to_timedelta(df['payment_plan_days'], unit='d')
print (df)
   payment_plan_days transaction_date        new
0                 30       1970-01-01 1970-01-31
1                 70       2005-07-17 2005-09-25
2                100       2005-07-17 2005-10-25
```

Comment: That is it! Will accept it after 10 minutes limit. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Same idea as jezrael answer only using datetime's timedelta function:

```
from datetime import timedelta
dates=pd.to_datetime(['1970-01-01','2005-07-17', '2005-07-17'])
df = pd.DataFrame({'transaction_date':dates, 'payment_plan_days':[30,70,100]})
df.loc[:, 'expiration_date'] = list(map(lambda td, ppd: td+timedelta(ppd), df['transaction_date'], df['payment_plan_days']))
```